# How to run Apache Wild Card script on localhost?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, wamp, wildcard

My I am a HTML/CSS dev, and one of my friends gave me a codeigniter script and told me to edit everything in the views folder. When I put the code into WAMP, I just get the error "shop not found". I asked my friend, and he said that he uses Apache wild card, and I would have to set it up differently! He then just went offline, and hasn't replied to my posts. He creates a subdomain per person like [person].domain.com. Any way I can set this up on localhost?

Comment: I am not sure if this is right, but I think i have to add this in the hosts file? http://puu.sh/47QBU.png

Comment: That would not go into your hosts file, it would go into you apache virtual host configuration file: httpd-vhosts.conf (which needs to be included in the main apache configuration file, httpd.conf). Your hosts file would look like this (hosts is at the bottom): http://offshootinc.com/blog/2007/12/21/setting-up-a-subdomain-on-localhost/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Helped me out a lot. You should have posted an answer so i could have +1 it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't post as an answer because I wasn't sure I was addressing the question you were asking. If all you wanted was info on how to set up virtual hosts in WAMP, there is a good guide here: http://offshootinc.com/blog/2007/12/21/setting-up-a-subdomain-on-localhost/ (as mentioned) that should also explain how you vhost configuration file should look, as well as your hosts file, if you are only using this on your local machine.

I'm glad my comment got you headed in the right direction. If you feel like this answered your question, hopefully you will mark it, otherwise, it might help to clarify what your question is here.